# Is every predictable process a pointwise limit of left-continuous, adapted processes?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

> Define the predictable $\sigma$-algebra as
>   $$
> \mathcal P := \sigma(X: \text{ $X$ is a left-continuous and adapted process }),
> $$
>   and say that a stochastic process is predictable if  it is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal P$. [The stochastic processes are assumed to take values in some Polish space $E$ and be indexed by $[0,\infty)$]

As measurablility is preserved under pointwise limits, a pointwise limit of left-continuous and adapted processes will be predictable.

> Is it true that any predictable process is a pointwise limit (or even a.s. pointwise limit if we assume our probability space is complete) of a sequence of left-continuous and adapted processes.?

More generally, is it always true that if we define $\mathcal F := \sigma(f: \text{ $ f $ with some property })$, then every $\mathcal F $-measurable function is the limit of a sequence of functions with that same property?

Comment: Regarding your question on predictable processes as pointwise limits: Yes, I think so. Take a look at Theorem 1.2.24 in "Martingales and Stochastic Analysis" by J. Yeh

Comment: @saz The Theorem I.2.24 in Yeh's book is not convinced, because its proof depends on the Proposition I.1.12 and there is a bug in the proof of Prop. I.1.12.(How to verify "the **V** statisfies condition $2^\circ$")

Answer (score 4):

Any pointwise limit of  left-continuous adapted processes would have sample paths $t\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ that were, at worst, in the fourth Baire class.  Thus a deterministic process $X_t(\omega)=f(t)$, for a Borel function $f$ of the fifth Baire class, is not the pointwise limit of the type you request.

The good news is that any argument you might be trying to make based on such a pointwise approximation "fact" can likely be made through the use of the functional monotone class theorem.

Comment: Could you please expand on why they can be at worst Baire class 4? Is it something that holds true for all left-continuous functions?

Comment: Yes.  Think of approximating a left-continuous function by left-continuous step functions. The "4" we erring on the safe side.

Comment: A left-continuous step function (ie the indicator function of some semiopen interval) is Baire 1. A left-continuous function should therefore be Baire 2, and limits of left-continuous Baire 3. Why did you say "4"?

Comment: I mean, I understand that a deterministic Baire 5 function works as a counterexample to the question of the OP, but so does a function in, say, Baire 1000. My question is about optimality.

Comment: @Titti Not sure why 4 specifically — this was written 18 months ago.  Guess: I took 2 and doubled it to be safe..

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the generalization is true because the property could be too narrow.  For example, consider functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ equipped with the Borel sigma algebra.  If we let $\mathcal{F} := \sigma(f :  f(x) = x \text{ for all $x \in [0,1]$})$ then $\mathcal{F}$ is the Borel sigma algebra on $[0,1]$, but the only function that can be obtained by limits of functions with that property is the identity.

Comment: Great counterexample! Thanks!